# Denied permission to create a directory

Tags: raspbian, permissions

I am installing openvpn and in one of the first steps I have to create the following directory: /etc/openvpn/certs with the mkdir command. However I always get the error: cannot create the directory, permission denied.

I tried as well to do it with the graphical interface (file manager) with the same result.

I am using the raspbian system with standard user (pi).

Many thanks for your help,

Jose.

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo` in front of the command?

Answer (score 1):

Does pi have write permissions in /etc/openvpn folder? First guide I found says to do that with root permissions so I'd rather suggest doing 'sudo mkdir'.