# Permission Denied - Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I've been trying to edit my opt\vc file and encountered some problems:

here is what i've done:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/opt/vc $ mkdir NEW
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘NEW’: Permission denied
```

i'm pretty new at this so i don't really know what to do.
can anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Denied permission to create a directory](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50684/denied-permission-to-create-a-directory)

Comment: every-time you see "Permission Denied" try using sudo  every time. Seriously , we should make a Rules post, and have this be Rule1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an ownership problem. /opt/vc will be owned by a different user (probably 'root'). Try:

```
sudo mkdir NEW
```

Answer (score 1):

Like recantha said, sudo mkdir will work. But if you want to to more things at once which require root-access the you can type sudo -s, which will change you to root-user. But then be careful, you are allowed to do everything which means you can destroy alot.

Answer (score -1):

This has helped me with the permission denied dialog: Whatever command you are using, navigate to it using the File Manager and access it's properties dialog. You should see two tabs at the top of the properties dialog, and one is labeled PERMISSIONS. Select the PERMISSIONS tab and make sure that the 1st and 3rd selections are set to ANYONE. That did it for me.

Comment: This is not the right way to deal with this. Your method may work but it can also create a large security vulnerability, using sudo is a much better option.